# Seek on Pickled Data

Tags: python, pickle, seek

Is it possible to jump to a specific record in a pickled file in Python please?

E.g.:

```py
import pickle

with open ('BinaryFile.dat', mode='wb') as MyFile:
    pickle.dump('Item1', MyFile)
    pickle.dump('Item2', MyFile)
    pickle.dump('Item3', MyFile)
    pickle.dump('Item4', MyFile)
    pickle.dump('Item5', MyFile)

with open('BinaryFile.dat', mode='rb') as MyReadFile:
    MyReadFile.seek(3)
    print(pickle.load(MyReadFile))
```

gives `_pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\x05'.`

Does seek even work on picked data? Do I need to call `pickle.load(MyReadFile)` multiple times instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pickle records can be concatenated into a file, so yes, you can just `pickle.load(f)` multiple times, but the files themselves are not indexed in a way that would let you seek into a given record.

What your `f.seek(3)` is doing is seeking into the third *byte* in the file, which is in the middle of a pickle record, and thus is unpicklable.

If you need random access, you might want to look into the [built-in `shelve` module](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/shelve.html#module-shelve) which builds a dictionary-like interface on top of `pickle` using a database file module.

(Another easy method would be to simply have a directory full of pickle files.)

Comment: So what about if I want to move backwards in the file? Is there a way to `pickle.unload(f)`?

Comment: No, but you can use `f.tell()` to figure out where in the file you are after each `.load()`, keep track of them, and `f.seek()` back to where you want to be.

Comment: Thanks. So I CAN use seek, but only if it points to the beginning of a record?

Comment: @RobinAndrews correct!

Answer (score 1):

You could do it by explicitly saving the starting location of each item using the file `tell()` method before calling `pickle.dump()`, and using that information later to reposition the file stream before `pickle.load()`.

Here's what I mean:

```
import pickle

indices = []

with open ('BinaryFile.dat', mode='wb') as MyFile:
    indices.append(MyFile.tell())
    pickle.dump('Item1', MyFile)
    indices.append(MyFile.tell())
    pickle.dump('Item2', MyFile)
    indices.append(MyFile.tell())
    pickle.dump('Item3', MyFile)
    indices.append(MyFile.tell())
    pickle.dump('Item4', MyFile)
    indices.append(MyFile.tell())
    pickle.dump('Item5', MyFile)

with open('BinaryFile.dat', mode='rb') as MyReadFile:
    MyReadFile.seek(indices[3])
    print(pickle.load(MyReadFile))  # -> Item4
```

Of course, for this to really be useful, you'll also need to save the location data the `indices` list, too.