# How to skip objects when unpickling in Python

Tags: python, indexing, io, pickle

I'm dumping many large objects in a file using `pickle` sequentially. Afterwards, I would like to read one of the objects *without loading all the objects in front of it*. As an example, consider a simple file containing only numbers.

```py
import pickle

# Save data
with open('example.p', 'ab') as f:
    for i in range(10):
        pickle.dump(i, f)
```

Afterwards, I would like to get the object at some given index. I have written a function as follows:

```py
# Load data
def get_ith_object (index):
    with open('example.p', 'rb') as f:
        for i in range(index+1):
            obj = pickle.load(f)
            if i == index:
                return obj
            
print(get_ith_object(5)) # prints "5"
```

While this works, it can take very long to reach the `i`th object when the file contains many large objects. Is there a way I can skip objects, and jump to the `i`th object directly (or reasonably fast)?

Related question: [Seek on Pickled Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55809976/seek-on-pickled-data)

Comment: I've never really seen a single pickle file used for multiple distinct objects. In turn it is much easier to have a separate file per object that you'd like to pickle. That way you can load what you like directly.

Comment: @EddieBergman i'm saving 10000+ objects. Opening, writing, and closing a file for every single object takes too long. Plus, it saves unnecessary metadata...

Comment: One possibility is to just store all your objects in a list and pickle this one list. As far as I'm aware, since the pickle files are a byte stream, it's not easy to directly know and access the file exactly where the byte stream for one particular object is. You will always be forced to load the entire pickle file.

Answer (score 1):

First, get the size of the integer.

```
with open('example.p', 'rb') as f:
    obj = pickle.load(f)
    print(f"An integer's size is {f.tell()}.")
    size = f.tell()
```

```
An integer's size is 5.
```

Second, use "f.seek" to set the offset.

```
target = 5

with open('example.p', 'rb') as f:
    f.seek(size*target, 0)
    obj = pickle.load(f)
    print(obj)
```

```
5
```

Comment: Thank you, this is close to what i'm looking for. The only problem is that in my real case, the objects are not necessarily integers and they don't have a fixed size.